# Ionic 3 geolocation error

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I am using the ionic native geolocation plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/ to get users current position. Everything works fine apart from an issue I am experiencing when the user has his phones location turned off, then the app cannot turn it back on even if the user allows location access.

```
        this.options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10000
        };
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos: Geoposition) => {
            this.currentLat = pos.coords.latitude;
            this.currentLon = pos.coords.longitude;

        );
        }, (err: PositionError) => {
            console.log("error : " + err.message);

        })
```

I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Comment: are you checking for geolocation before navigating to this page with maps.

Comment: yes I am, even navigate way from page come, back but still no luck

Comment: are you using any plugin to check location access? if so tell me which one

Comment: no, just using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/ to get position. works on browser but not on phone

Comment: no this is for using geolocation i am asking if you are using any plugin to check whether  your phones gps is on or off?

Comment: yes right then you first have to check if the location access is off and then move to the maps page or trigger it before displaying maps.

Comment: ok, let me try using https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin to check it first

Comment: yes exactly use that plugin to check the location access. i will share my code example to make it simpler to you on its usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has his device location off then you need to check it using ionic native diagnostic plugin and if location is off take user to locationSettings

```
this.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled().then(state => {
  if (!state) {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: '<b>Location</b>',
      message: 'Location information is unavaliable on this device. Go to Settings to enable Location.',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'cancel',
          role: 'Cancel',
          handler: () => {
            this.navCtrl.push(alternatePage); // this is optional(you can use only one button if maps is necessary) according to your needs if you want to navigate user to some other place if he does not give location access.
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Go to settings,
          handler: () => {
            this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings()
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
  else {
    this.navCtrl.push(yourMapsPage) // if access is available take to maps page. 
  }
})
```